# Add/Update form actions(context?) detection from hook_buildForm

Tags: hooks

Is it possible in hook_buildForm to define which "$action" link (view/add/update/delete/etc) opens the form? We need to set different $defaults depending on "context". There is such kind of detection/check in TPL files, but what about hook_buildForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be it:

```
    $mode = $form->getVar('_mode');
    // civicrm mumbo jumbo below targets EDIT form mode
    if (in_array($mode, array(CRM_Profile_Form::MODE_EDIT))) 
    {}
```

But it doesn't work for all forms, so, for example, for Relationship add/edit form, we should check if **$form->getVar('_relationshipId')**  isset/empty :
thus no Relationship has been created  yet: we are in Relationship ADD "mode".